Custom Domain not working without www in the front
I have purchased a custom domain and hosting service from Cloudflare. I am using Azure CDN for front end caching & delivering static content from Azure Storage Account (Static web hosting)
I have the following configuration in the DNS record management in cloudflare:
.
I have the following configuration in Azure CDN as redirect rule & added a custom domain:

Added Custom Domain:

The site works when I type www.sruthianem.com. But it does not work when I type sruthianem.com. I am not sure what am I missing.
I get a Page not found error.

You have a CNAME record at the domain apex. This is not possible, because CNAME cannot coexist with other records (with few exceptions regarding DNSSEC), and a domain apex must have SOA & NS records. See RFC 1912, 2.4.

Thanks. Can you please let me know what is the suggested configuration? I am not 100% clear.

Sometimes it is possible to add an A record instead of the CNAME, but as some services don't support that, sometimes the only solution is to use the subdomain as the canonical address and HTTP redirect to it elsewhere.

Personally I don't like adding CNAMEs for external services, because SPF does not support inheritance. Therefore, any hosname with an A record but without the SPF policy can be used as an envelope sender in SMTP.
